# How not to escape an ampersand with python subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, subprocess, unc

I'd like to execute with `subprocess.Popen()` this command containing an ampersand to be interpreted as a batch concatenation operator:

```
COMMAND="c:\p\a.exe & python run.py"
subprocess.Popen(COMMAND,cwd=wd,shell=False)`
```

The ampersand `&` however is interpreted as an argument of `a.exe` and not as a batch operator.

**Solution 1:** Having seen the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120657/python-subprocess-issue-with-ampersands), a solution could be to set `shell=True` but that gives the error 'UNC path are not supported', since my working directory is remote. This solution does not work as it is.

**Solution2:** The executable `a.exe` should take a `-inputDir` parameter to specify the remote location of the files and use a local working directory. I think this solution could work but I may not have the source code of the executable.

**Solution3:** I could instead write `c:\p\a.exe & python run.py` into `command.bat` and then use

```
COMMAND="c:\p\command.bat"
subprocess.Popen(COMMAND,cwd=wd,shell=False)`
```

Could this approach work?

**Solution4:** I am trying to solve this changing only the `subprocess.Popen()` call. Is it possible to do it? Based on the [python Popen doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) I suspect is not possible. Please tell me I am wrong.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes) related questions.

**UPDATE:**

Solution 5: @mata suggested to use Powershell `Popen(['powershell', '-Command', r'C:\p\a.exe; python run.py'])`. This actually works, but now I have to deal with slightly different commands, and being lazy I've decided to use solution 3.

My favourite solution was Solution 3, to create a `.bat` file and call it

```
COMMAND="c:\p\command.bat"
subprocess.Popen(COMMAND,cwd=wd,shell=False)
```

Comment: Have you considered checking the return code yourself?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't see how checking return code helps here. I don't need to know `a.exe` return code.

Comment: I think Ignacio ment to run one command, then when that finishes run the other, so use two Popen calls instead of one, otherwise you're limited by `cmd` not supporting unc paths. You could use powershell if that's available: `Popen(['powershell', '-Command', r'C:\p\a.exe; python run.py'])` instead.

Comment: Thanks @mata its a good suggestion. I've tried it and almost works, but `powershell -command` then splits the arguments in a different way, I'm still working on it.

Comment: Are you saying that the solution #1: `call(r'c:\p\a.exe & python run.py', cwd=wd, shell=True)` causes the UNC error but the solution #3: `call(r'c:\p\command.bat', cwd=wd)` which executes the same command but from the batch-file works? Have you tried the obvious: `call(r'c:\p\a.exe', cwd=wd); call('python run.py', cwd=wd)` instead?

Comment: Hint: where the code says `shell = False`, what effect do you suppose that has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Solution 3`

```
The & character is used to separate multiple commands on one command line. 
Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.
```

In this case you could just write your batch file like this:

```
@echo off
c:\p\a.exe
python run.py
```

Also, it's worth noting when using cmd.exe:

```
The ampersand (&), pipe (|), and parentheses ( ) are special characters
that must be preceded by the escape character (^) or quotation marks
when you pass them as arguments.
```

Comment: I've tried all these approaches and this seems the more reasonable. Using `powershell -Command` create problem due to the different way it splits the parameters and due to the fact that I couldn't ignore interactive prompt boxes with it. Passing a `.bat` is now my favourite, since I can also keep `Shell=False`